# MDX retrieve recordset

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssas, mdx

I am trying to match existing reporting functionality while building up a new cube for a Proof of Concept.

Can I retrieve data from my cube using an MDX query and put it into a recordset so I can then populate an Excel Sheet with the data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered attaching from Excel directly to Analysis Services, and using the built-in drag-and-drop query functionality?  Excel will generate the MDX for you.

I've never done it, but it should be possible to integrate ADOMD.NET into a VSTO application, which will then run inside Excel.  You might also be able to access some of Excel's MDX query machinery directly that way....

Comment: Well, an ADoMD recordset comes in the format of a Cubed recordset. Fantastically enough, I actually have a scenario where I need to do flat file extacts out of EXCEL.

Comment: You could also say that the response to all MDX queries is a "cubed recordset."

It's a straightforward process to transform a CellSet (the ADOMD equivalent of a DataSet) into a two-dimensional object.  In case it helps, I give a detailed example in my book (Ultra-Fast ASP.NET).

Answer (score 1):

Best way to work with OLAP and Excel is detailed here: [Simpler interface for SQL Server analysis services cubes for end users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876/simpler-interface-for-sql-server-analysis-services-cubes-for-end-users/70515)

If you want to write your own MDX instead of using drag-drop, you can't do this with Excel as far as I know. However, most languages would let you fire off some MDX at a cube, and then you could loop the recordset yourself to create a CSV file.

Or even simpler, use SQL Server's Query Analyser like this, and save the results to a CSV:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLAP',
'Datasource=MyHotServer;Initial catalog=MyLovelyCube',
'SELECT {dimensions(0).members} ON ROWS, {time.defaultmember} ON COLUMNS FROM sales')
```

*(N.B. If you don't know MDX yet....don't start learning unless you really have to! It isn't as easy as SQL, and you can get away without it usually.)*